# Time series analysis where computing the exact value is possible (but expensive)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I have a stationary time series where it is actually possible for me to compute the exact next value. These computations are very expensive, and to speed things up I want to employ following scheme:

1) Fit an ARIMA model to the observations

2) Forecast the next $n$ steps

3) At $n+1$, perform an exact calculation

4) Refit the model using the predicted values plus the observation at $n+1$ to predict the next $n$ steps

I implemented this scheme, and it works "quite well" for a short time, but the values diverges rather quickly to infinity. I cannot really explain why this happens, but I assume that the reason is that I use predicted values (which have an error) to refit my ARIMA model? Also I am wondering, whether somebody knows of a better approach/has a different idea to tackle this problem.

I very much appreciate any help.

Cheers